# Firebase retriving single text data and setting it in a textview

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, textview

I have been trying to retrieve only the username data saved in firebase and have it displayed in a text view on navigation drawer but I either keep getting errors and app crashes or nothing gets displayed in the text view and app doesn't crash. app doesn't crash with this code.

[image: app]

This is my database

[image: This is my database]

Data Model

```
public class users {
    private String userID;
    private String userEmail;
    private String userName;
    private String userUsername;


    public users() {

    }

    public users(String userID, String userEmail, String userName, String userUsername) {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userUsername = userUsername;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getUserUsername() {
        return userUsername;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public void setUserUsername(String userUsername) {
        this.userUsername = userUsername;
    }
}
```

Main Activity

```
//ASSIGNING FIREBASE OBJECTS.
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mFire = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
userID = user.getUid();

mDatabase = mFire.getReference("users");
usernameRef = mDatabase.child(userID);


//METHODS
checkIfUserSignedIN();
InitImgLoader();
setProfileImg();



//NAVIGATION LAYOUT.
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



//HEADER VIEW LAYOUT.
username = findViewById(R.id.Username_onDrawer);
View headView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
ImageView pp = headView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
pp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});

usernameRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


       for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("userUsername").getChildren()){
            users usernamE = new users();
            usernamE.setUserUsername(ds.child(userID).getValue(users.class).getUserUsername());


            username.setText(usernamE.getUserUsername());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

[I'm trying to set username below this image view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWUnt.jpg)

**UPDATE!***strong text*****
It only seems to work if I have the database like this with the following code..

```
 mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                String UserUserName = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("userUsername").getValue());


                username.setText(UserUserName);

            }
```

[database with No user id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Uk1L.png)

This is how i saved the data to firebase

```
 //USER SIGNUP INFORMATION METHOD.
private void push(){

    String Email = email.getText().toString().trim();
    String Name = name.getText().toString().trim();
    String Username = userName.getText().toString().trim();

    String id = mDatabase.push().getKey();

    users Users = new users(id, Email, Name, Username);

    mDatabase.child(id).setValue(Users);
```

Comment: you have added listener on `usernameRef`, which points to `/users/<userId>`, so you should just use `usernamE = dataSnapshot.getValue(users.class)`. If you need only `userUsername`, add listener to `/users/<userId>/userUsername`

Comment: still causes crash :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I have used the `uid` as the unique identified and not the pushed key generated by the `push()` method. So for that, change the following lines of code:

```
String id = mDatabase.push().getKey();
users Users = new users(id, Email, Name, Username);
mDatabase.child(id).setValue(Users);
```

with:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
users Users = new users(uid, Email, Name, Username);
mDatabase.child(uid).setValue(Users);
```

To get the data from the databse, please use the following code using the String class:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String userEmail = dataSnapshot.child("userEmail").getValue(String.class);
        String userID = dataSnapshot.child("userID").getValue(String.class);
        String userName = dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue(String.class);
        String userUsername = dataSnapshot.child("userUsername").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", userEmail + " / " + userID + " / " + userName + " / " + userUsername);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

If you want to use the model class, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        users u = dataSnapshot.getValue(users.class);
        String userEmail = u.getUserEmail();
        String userID = u.getUserID();
        String userName = u.getUserName();
        String userUsername = u.getUserUsername();
        Log.d("TAG", userEmail + " / " + userID + " / " + userName + " / " + userUsername);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In both cases, delete all the data that you and add fresh one.

Comment: This is the answer!  Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the username, you can do this:

```
usernameRef = mDatabase.child(userID);
usernameRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        String names=dataSnapshot.child("userUsername").getValue().toString();
        username.setText(names);


}
```

the snapshot would be the `userid`, and then you do not need to iterate, can just access it since its a direct child.

Comment: this way still makes the app crash. I added a update to this post. I think it may have something to do with the firebase push() function...? thanks anyway

Comment: @user8360723 no check the edit now it will work, I wrote here `child("username")` instead of `child("userUsername")`

Comment: yeaa noticed that lol I have to many "user" name variables... Anyway it would still cause app to crash. It works only if I have no user id key in my database

Comment: maybe there is no currentuser